# map is isomorphism if complex is of finite type

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In Bredons Topology book, in the chapter 3. The Cohomologiy cross product, Theorem 3.2 he claims that the map:
$$ \gamma: Hom(H_{\star}(X),\Delta)\otimes Hom(H_{\star}(Y),\Delta) \to Hom(H_{\star}(X) \otimes H_{\star}(Y),\Delta)$$
given by (I suppose?) $\gamma(f, g) = f \otimes g$ (is this right?) is an isomorphism if $H_{\star}(X)$ or $H_{\star}(Y)$ is of finite type i.e for all degrees its finetly generated. Why is this true?

Comment: Yes, your $\gamma$ is correct. Note that Bredon's notation uses $\Lambda$ not $\Delta$ in what you have above, and $\Lambda$ is a field. Then this is a special case of a more general fact, which is that (in $R$-modules) the analogue of $\gamma$, a map $Hom(A,S) \otimes Hom(B,T) \to Hom(A \otimes B, S \otimes T)$, is an isomorphism if one of the pairs $(A,S)$ or $(B,T)$ or $(A,B)$ consists of projective modules of finite type. In the case $R = \Lambda$ field, all $\Lambda$-vector spaces are free hence projective. The finite type assumption on $A=H_*X$ or $B = H_*Y$ finishes the argument.

Comment: is there a not to complicated way to see this, or where can I look this up?

Comment: Yes: for your case (working over a field), the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255896/commuting-of-hom-and-tensor-product-functors suffices, and that answer has a reference to this general fact.